# Axios set URL for GET request from the GET request response

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

This question is very similar to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061162/update-axios-request-for-pagination)

I have set up a Vue page with Laravel and showing all posts with a help of a GET request. I am also listening to a Laravel ECHO event and `unshifting` the value to the all posts array making it appear on top.

I have set up the infinite scroll and paginating 5 results per page using [this package](https://github.com/juampi92/cursor-pagination). Results appear on the page and pushing to the array from the listener also works. However, when infinite scroll loads the 2nd results page, the 6th result is duplicated.

The aforementioned package accepts `next_cursor` an offset value as the parameter instead of `page=2` so it exactly loads the value without any duplications.

**Controller.php**

```php
    public function pusherGet(Request $request) {
        $jobs = Job::orderBy('id','desc')->cursorPaginate();        
        return response()->json($jobs);
    }
```

**Vue file**

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <h3 class="text-center">All Jobs</h3><br/>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card" v-for="(job,index) in jobs" :key="index">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{ job.id }}</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ job.request_type}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <infinite-loading  @infinite="getJob"></infinite-loading>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                   page:1,
                   jobs: [],                
                }
            },       
            mounted() {           
                this.listenNewJobs();  
            },
            created() {
           
            },
            methods: {            
                listenNewJobs() {
                    Echo.channel('chat-room.1')
                        .listen('JobCreated', (e) => {
                            console.log(e);                        
                            this.jobs.unshift(e.job);                            
                        });
                    },
                    getJob($state) {
                        axios.get('getjobs', {                
                            params: {
                                page: this.page,                        
                            },
                       }).then(({data})=> {
                           console.log(data) 
                           if(data.data.length) {
                               this.page += 1;
                               this.jobs.push(...data.data)
                               $state.loaded();
                            } else {
                            $state.complete();
                        }
                    });                     
                }
            }        
        }
    </script>
```

**Results Json**

```json
    {
        data: Array(5), path: "getjobs?page=1", previous_cursor: "100", next_cursor: "96", per_page: 5, …}
        data: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
        next_cursor: "96" // this is the parameter which i should attach to the GET request to paginate correct results
        next_page_url: "getjobs?page=1&next_cursor=96"
path: "getjobs?page=1"
        per_page: 5
        prev_page_url: "getjobs?page=1&previous_cursor=100"
previous_cursor: "100"
        __proto__: Object
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit : How to Set the URL for the GET request to paginate the results from the GET request response for paginated results to avoid 2nd page result duplication ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ConnorLow How to Set the URL for the GET request to paginate the results from the GET request response for paginated results to avoid 2nd page result duplication

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        jobs: [],
        isInitialLoaded: false,
        currentPage: 1,
        lastPage: 0,
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.listenNewJobs();
    },
    created() {
      //
    },
    methods: {
      listenNewJobs() {
        Echo.channel('chat-room.1')
          .listen('JobCreated', (e) => {
              console.log(e);
              this.jobs.unshift(e.job);
        });
      },
      async getJob($state){
        await this.fetchData().then((response) => {
          this.lastPage = response.data.last_page;
          if (response.data.data.length > 0) {
            response.data.data.forEach((item) => {
              const exists = this.jobs.find((job) => job.id == item.id);
              if (!exists) {
                // this.jobs.unshift(item); // Add to front of array
                this.jobs.push(item);
              }
            });
            if (this.currentPage - 1 === this.lastPage) {
              this.currentPage = 2;
              $state.complete();
            } else {
              this.currentPage += 1;
            }
            $state.loaded();
          } else {
            this.currentPage = 2;
            $state.complete();
          }
        });
        this.isInitialLoaded = true;
      },
      fetchData() {
        const url = this.isInitialLoaded ? `/getjobs?page=${this.currentPage}` : `/getjobs`;
        return axios.get(url);
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, i am getting a `Property or method "jobs" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` when it is initialized

Comment: In the method add `const self = this;` and change all the `this` to `self`. It's probably losing the binding to this but throwing it into a constant of self will ensure it keeps that inside the callback.

Comment: Changed it accordingly, yet no luck, throwing the same error.

Comment: Very weird, i added your method to my previous script code and it works great. I wonder a cache is remained in the script, i stopped and started npm watch as well. Thanks for the great help

Comment: An Arrow function ["_Does not have its own bindings to `this`_"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so assigning to `self` And using that should make no difference.